# Why my CGI Script can't access to ttyUSB0?

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, serial-port, cgi

I'm having a CGI script in C language, which open the serial port ttyUSB0 in my Raspberry pi, send a data at my device and get it response.

This script perform correctly when i'm launch it manually in the terminal but my web page can't access to this port to open it.

My code :

```
int main (void) {

  printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

  const int fd = open ("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);

  if (fd == -1)
  {
        printf ("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, "ttyUSB0", strerror (errno));
        return 0;
  }
```

And the response in the web page : "***error 13 opening ttyUSB0: Permission denied***"

And below the output of the command "id -Gn pi" :
pi adm tty uucp dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio lpadmin

Thanks.

Comment: *"Manual"* execution of program is from shell as a user that is in the group that owns tty device, e.g. the group **dialout**. Execution as CGI script has a different process owner that is not in the group that owns tty device. Simple and proper solution is add that process user to **dialout** group.

Comment: I'm reading some problems like mind where the solution was to add dialout in the group like your purpose but after using the command : "sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi" my problem wasn't fixed. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: How did you verify who the process owner was for the CGI script?

Comment: Just by searching in differents topics of forum and by using the ls -l /ttyUSB0 is using by the group dialout.
Then if i'm using the command : "top" and i do a request, apache appear to execute with the user www-data so some people ask to execute the command "sudo adduser www-data dialout" but this didn't fix my problem.
Could you help me ?

Comment: My problem was solved with the command sudo adduser www-data dialout and rebooting the system sorry for the wasted time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command below solved my problem :

```
sudo adduser www-data dialout
```